# Run configuration via SSH error - Needs read action

Tags: intellij-idea

When I try to run a app remotely via ssh in IntelliJ Idea. I got the follow error message:

```
Error running 'application-ssh': Failed to prepare target. Needs read action
```

The ssh connection is established successful. Test is successful. The connection is established some of the files are transferred, but after a while it is failing with that error message. Same is happening for with and without rsync option. Full prepare log:

```
Prepare target requirements...
Connecting to xxx-xxx...
Set up uploading volume file:///Users/xxx/workspace/xxxx/xxx-xxx-xxx ==> ssh://xxx-xxx/home/xxx/xxx-xxx/CxjhG9Akc0
Set up batch uploading volume file:///Users/xxx ==> ssh://xxx-xxx/home/xxx/xxx-xxx/3W0BPZ7AA2 for paths
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.5.3/e25d2de9e166a8bbbfae633fc03220ab36ac19a9
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/25ea2e8b0c338a877313bd4672d3fe056ea78f0d
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.4/f3bc99fd0b226065012b24fe9f808299048bab54
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.5.21/2f537cad7e9eeb9da73738c8812e1e4cf9b62e4e
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/5.3.9/f5ca763cfb9d62d196efd5d25e8daca7d555ed75
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jakarta.annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/59eb84ee0d616332ff44aba065f3888cf002cd2d
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.5.21/802f1f39735ae1eb2b75714a40fa19bb2e687e96
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.32/8a055c04ab44e8e8326901cadf89080721348bdb
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.5.21/cc8bf3586fd2ebcf234058b9440bb406e62dfacb
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.xerial.snappy/snappy-java/1.1.7.7/43d5dbd718e6b0b1f0c8b234f2a9bb6385b8afde
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/5.3.9/887f4579ade4f47cf0102856f4f4c88eda8ec9d7
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.5.3/f03d7e9102d93ab25110da850be9facf11818a0b
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/5.3.9/48600db2cb1abc0f7ef2b073f0c1abd78a83bcfc
   workspace/xxx/xxx-xxx-xxx/build/classes/kotlin/main
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka/2.7.4/5968e3cd8bb20c187454e8a35bedc5a8b6c7529f
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.luben/zstd-jni/1.4.5-6/3213bb3b3f54644817f422bda3be347eaf4915a7
   workspace/xxx/xxx-xxx-xxx/build/resources/main
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.21/6b3de2a43405a65502728047db37a98a0c7e72f0
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/5.3.9/9bcad31a74e60d205500dd67d2220bd0195c63f8
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jcl/5.3.9/622eb12c98768b6d3acc71ce06bac8b332607a10
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.retry/spring-retry/1.3.1/f8644c86f2be54623c3b336a56b54216841a3f22
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.21/f059658740a4b3a3461aba9681457615332bae1c
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.2.4/5f429ee58dbacf9040f846f1218c36ca6e851596
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.3.9/a7057cf30368d014a1c8e5880a128703c890ec79
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.lz4/lz4-java/1.7.1/c4d931ef8ad2c9c35d65b231a33e61428472d0da
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.32/cdcff33940d9f2de763bc41ea05a0be5941176c3
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.5.3/2e16fb3d63961548468a2cd70015d4b1be968fd4
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.3.9/cfef19d1dfa41d56f8de66238dc015334997d573
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.5.3/a3a2057be09b4105ecf2e7e3097e0e3fe2eb2684
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-messaging/5.3.9/bcce428a1648c8b8814203bcc6dee1028280b6f6
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.14.1/cd8858fbbde69f46bce8db1152c18a43328aae78
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.14.1/ce8a86a3f50a4304749828ce68e7478cafbc8039
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.28/7cae037c3014350c923776548e71c9feb7a69259
   .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/2.7.1/11c152973cbf7367cae6f61a4d2584bf5a774451
Needs read action

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: Please submit a new issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide the IDE logs. (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data) Try using the latest version from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2021.2+latest+builds .

Comment: @EgorKlepikov - Request #3449519

Comment: Any update? I have the same issue.

Comment: @sssemil, seems to be fixed - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-273231